# mysqli_insert query not executing in PHP

Tags: php

When i run this code, It always goes in the else block. what is wrong with the if condition or the insert query ?

```
<?php
require 'foodconfiguration.php';
$name="Ankita Mukreji";
$email="xyz@gmail.com";
$password="ankita1234";
$contact="9820213123";

$sqlquery="select * from users where email LIKE '$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sqlquery);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
$sqlinsertquery="insert into users (name,password,contact,email) values ('$name','$password','$contact','$email')";
$insertresult=mysqli_query($connection,$sqlinsertquery);
if($insertresult){
    echo "Registration Successful\n";
}
else
{
    echo mysqli_error();
}
}
else
{
echo "Email already Exists\n";  
}
?>
```

Comment: Add spaces before and after your parenthesis, this can cause your query to fail.

Comment: It runs fine on localhost. But shows some error when uploaded on server.

Comment: @AadeshKulkarni - please specify what "Some Error" is.

Comment: Also, please read this: http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP

Comment: @MarkPhillips error is "Invalid Data\" ;)

Comment: Is there any way to find whats the exact problem in mysqli_query($connection,$sqlinsertquery) ?

Comment: @AadeshKulkarni display **real** error, wchis is `echo mysqli_error($connection);`

Comment: Error as in it is echoing the else part "Invalid Data"

Comment: @nospor - haha yeah true, just hoping he had taken Marian Sabo's advice below and seen the SQL error :P

Comment: @AadeshKulkarni - please change echo "Invalid Data\n"; to echo mysqli_error(); and update us on to what the error is really.

Comment: @MarkPhillips I am afraid that OP looks like person who doesn't take advices ...

Comment: I changed it to echo mysqli_error(); and it displays nothing. Empty screen.

Comment: Could you edit the OP to provide us with the full segment of code?

Please remember to take out any sensitive information, such as passwords/usernames for your DB connection.

Comment: @AadeshKulkarni I've wrote you exactly code you must use. Code provided by Mark is not completed

Comment: @MarkPhillips try to give proper code next time :P mysqli_error require some parameter

Comment: just edited to full segment of code.

Comment: You still has wrong code. You still ignore my comments

Comment: Okay, @nospor . Thanks for the code.

Comment: I got the error. There was an additional field (address) in the table which i didnt wish to insert. got the following error " Field 'address' doesn't have a default value "

Comment: In regards to your latest comment:

$sqlinsertquery="insert into users (name,password,contact,email,address) values ('$name','$password','$contact','$email',NULL)";

Comment: You should also switch to a prepared query with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Troubleshooting can and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. used mysqli_error($connection); to find the actual error
2. It displayed the error --> Field 'address' doesn't have a default value <--
3. went to phpmyadmin->table->structure->ticked NULL for address field.
4. executed the code and it worked.

Thanks A lot @nospor, @Mark Philips and others.